# IIS Rewrite: HTTP to HTTPS and vice versa, why doesn't it work

Tags: c#, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have a page on which I have to redirect every HTTP Request to a HTTPS Request except on two pages where I have to do exactly the opposite because we include a remote 3rd party script which is loaded over HTTP.

Since this is a development environment (Visual Studio) the HTTP Port is 50382 and HTTPS is 44300.

Here is what I have so far (CustomerPortal is one of the exceptional pages).
It doesn't work and every request for CustomerPortal shows up as "canceled" in Chrome. I think to problem is the HTTP to HTTPS rule which doesn't exclude CustomerPortal.aspx, although I clearly added a condition for this case.

I have no idea why it doesn't work, I'm no expert at RegEx or IIS but to me the rules look correct (they obviously aren't).

```
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS on different SSL Port" enabled="true">
      <match url="^(.*\.aspx)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^50382$" />
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="CustomerPortal\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:44300/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Redirect to http 2">
      <match url="CustomerPortal\.aspx$"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^44300$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:50382/Guest/Portal/CustomerPortal.aspx" redirectType="Found" appendQueryString="true"  />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after further debugging and testing I have found the problem.
The rules itself are fine.
The problem was how I called *Response.Redirect* from within my c# code.

This doesn't work

```
Response.Redirect("~/Path/To/MyFile.aspx");
```

This does

```
Response.Redirect("http://mypage.com/Path/To/MyFile.aspx");
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. But if you use absolute paths when you redirect from HTTPS to HTTP and vice versa it works as expected.